# How to show $ \|fg\|_{L^2}\leq \|\partial_{x_1}f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2}\|\partial_{x_2}g\|_{L^2} $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Let $ f,g\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^2) $, show that
> $$
> \|fg\|_{L^2}\leq \|\partial_{x_1}f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2}\|\partial_{x_2}g\|_{L^2}.
> $$

Here is my try. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $ \operatorname{supp}(f,g)\subset\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+ $. Then I want to use the fundamental theorem of Calculus to represent $ fg $ by the $ \partial_{x_1}fg $ and $ f\partial_{x_2}g $. However I have some difficulty in this procedure. Can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: is this true ? if the compact support is unit rectangle and let $g \equiv 1,$ then this is claiming that $\|f\|_2\leq \|\partial_{x_1} f\|_2$, for which there should be easy counterexample.

Comment: @dezdichado: your $g$ does not have compact support.

Comment: @PhoemueX I was thinking $g$ would be cut-off at the boundary of the unit-rectangle and smoothed with bump functions around the edge. But then I guess changes things a bit.

Comment: Where does this come from?